# How can I navigate the activity to another activity in react native in a simple way?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to navigate my first page to the second page by tapping a button.
Once we are at the second page, we will never go back by pressing back button.

Just tap, switch, and never go back.

Is there any simple way to do this? 
I mean, I just don't want to use the component Navigation or Navigator. They are too complex.

Comment: I finally used the library--Navigation. Though it is a little bit complex.

Comment: Please share how you solved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using React Navigation from guide of Facebook.

You can read more about this library from:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

Or react navigation's website:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to avoid the navigator. This is awesome

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Once your scene keys are defined, you can navigate to them simply by calling Actions.*keyname*() on any screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how complex your app is, but if it's really simple you can do it this way:

```
const setScreen = (screen) => {
  setState({screen: screen})
}

render() {
  <View>
    {
      switch(this.state.screen) {
        case 'firstScreen': (
          <View>
            <Text>First Screen</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.setScreen('secondScreen')}>
              <Text>Go to second screen</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        )
        case 'secondScreen': (
          <View>
            <Text>Second Screen</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.setScreen('firstScreen')}>
              <Text>Go to first screen</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
  </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This mainly happens when we try to install a new package in our project and it does not get installed properly. I resolved this by

1. Delete `android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json` file.
2. Run `yarn` in the project root path.